# Want to make a software on VB.NET which decode Base64-encoded text strings and vice-versa

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a Software which decodes Base64-encoded text strings and vice versa.
Any help provided on the topic with coding in Visual Basic will help me a lot.
Thank you.
Note:-c# language can also be implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

These methods convert byte arrays to and from Base64.

If you want to encode a string in Base64, you'll need to convert it to a byte array by calling `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)` and `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)`.  (In the `System.Text` namespace)

Note that Base64 should  **never** be used for encryption, except to convert a byte array that was already encrypted into a string.

If you want to encrypt data, use the [`RijndaelManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert.FromBase64String. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx.

If you really want to know how to do it yourself - here are instructions for Java which you can reverse for decode. http://www.wikihow.com/Encode-a-String-to-Base64-With-Java

Comment: Do not re-invent the wheel. Note that there are also `ToBase64Transform` and `FromBase64Transform` classes.